# Configuring Initial networking of DOM-0 in XEN

Tags: virtualization, xen, hypervisor

I have installed CENT OS 5.4 with **Hypervisor**(XEN) on a blade server. When I log in in to 
the console and fire the command 'xm list', I can see domain-0. So Hypervisor is installed successfully. But I am not able to bring this machine on the network.

In 'ifconfig -a' I can see virtual interfaces(veth0, veth1 and associated vif) and bridge interfaces(xenbr0 and virbr0) created, but assigning IP to any of them is not helping because even after doing this machine is not coming on the network.

As I am completely new to XEN, I was going through xensource document to configure the networking where I learned about 'bridge' concept. But I was unable to get a clear idea of the
architecture and that's why unable to configure the IP addresses of interfaces and bring them on network.

As of now I have not installed any guest os(VM) on this machine, and for now objective is to bring the host machine on network.

Can anyone of you be able to guide me how to (which interfaces) configure networking here. And also provide link to some comprehensible document, if available, which will guide me through whole configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Is this any good ? [Wiki](http://wiki.xensource.com/xenwiki/XenNetworking)

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I have already had an overview of this document, and I found it complex and little hard to interpret. I will try to understand it! Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem. It's not straight forward but as with most of these things once you've got it working, it is. Easy when you know how ! Here's a site with lots more info: http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect_xen_setup_debian_ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I think the quick answer is:
Put the IP to the bridge, clear the ip on your Interface card and attach it to the bridge.

Make sure the bridge and your nic are both "up".

Have a look at /etc/xen/scripts/network-bridge and its parameters - that script should do all neccessary steps for you (if that script exists on CO5 - I use SLES).